# Change Access autonumber value

Tags: sql, ms-access, auto-increment, autonumber

I have a legacy Access database. The VB code in it needs a special record with the autonumber ID value `1` in a specific table.

The table in question has a primary key as autonumber. That column is also referenced in other tables as foreign key. That is why I cannot delete or modify the primary key of the table.

I tried to reset the counter with

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN tId COUNTER(1,1)
```

But it says I cannot change the table. And I cannot set the column value manually.

How can I put a specific value in an existing primary key autonumber column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADOX to change the seed of an autonumber field in Access:

```
Public Sub SetAutonumber(TableName As String, ColumnName As String, Seed As Long)
    Dim c As Object 'ADOX.Catalog
    Set c = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Set c.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    c.Tables(TableName).Columns(ColumnName).Properties("Seed") = Seed
End Sub
```

Invoke it using the immediate window:

```
SetAutonumber "MyTable", "tId", 1
```

And remember to reset it:

```
SetAutonumber "MyTable", "tId", DMAX("tId", "MyTable") + 1
```

Note, though, that Access allows inserts into the autonumber field. It's only read-only through the GUI, but queries and VBA are allowed to change it.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (tId) VALUES(1)
```

That might bypass the need to set and then reset the seed.

Also note: negative autonumbers are allowed in Access (autonumber fields are always signed), but never occur without manually setting the seed/setting them/corruption